# Slow loading of Odoo translations

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10, debian-jessie

I have an issue with slow loading of translations in Odoo when the checkbox "Overwrite Existing Terms" is selected.
The issue is reproducible on two servers but I can not reproduce it locally.

I have tried following things:

- To remove all custom modules
- To optimize configuration file for PostgreSQL.
- Searching for an error in PostgreSQL and Odoo logs

But I can not figure out still what is the issue.

I am using Odoo v.10 on Debian 8.7 Server and Postgresql 9.4

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So when you load the a translation with `Overwrite Existing Terms` selected  you have delay? Or after the loading of the translation you face delays navigating Odoo?

Comment: The delay is while the translation is loading